# How would I create exceptions in WorldEdit when setting blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit

I want to place snow in a selection, but I only want the snow to be placed on `grass_block`. Is this possible, and if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

- [`//overlay`](https://minecraft-worldedit.fandom.com/wiki///overlay) if the entire region is covered in grass
- or a [mask](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/general/masks/), specifically an [offset mask](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/general/masks/#offset-mask), inside the replace command. `//replace >grass_block snow`